# Calculate BMI using command line arguments inputs

Tags: java, command-line, command-line-arguments

first question here. I have to use a previous assignment of calculating BMI, and reformat it to accept command line arguments as inputs for height and weight.

"Your program shall obtain the weight and the height via main(String[] args), i.e,, when you run your program you must do the following:
java MyProgramName 180 5 7
where MyProgramName is the name of your program, 180 is the weight in pounds, 5 is the feet and 7 is the inch values.
The program shall output the BMI value in the terminal window as it was before (item f below)."

I am confused on how to call the arguments into the code while performing operands on them. 
Here is my original code:

```
'int weight;
int heightInInches;
int bmi;

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter your weight in pounds: ");
weight = keyboard.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter your height in inches: ");
heightInInches = keyboard.nextInt();

bmi = ((weight * 703)/(heightInInches * heightInInches));

System.out.println("Your height is " + heightInInches + " and your 
weight is: " + weight + " pounds");
System.out.println("Your BMI is " + bmi);'
```

I have seen something like this for just adding two numbers, but am confused how to alter it to the BMI formula.

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
}
System.out.println("The sum of the arguments passed is " + sum);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `String[] args` would look something like the s: `["180","5","7"]`

So `args[0]` would be your weight.

`args[1]` would be the heightInFeet (multiply by 12 to get heightInInches)

`args[2]` would be the inches part of the height

So the code becomes:

```
int weight = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int heightInInches = Integer.parseInt(args[1])*12 + Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
bmi = ((weight * 703)/(heightInInches * heightInInches));
```